# Blank popup in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer, moss, web-parts

I am trying to connect a filter web part with a document list web part but the popup showing the options for filtering is blank.

What I am doing. I have, as I described before, a QueryStringFilter web part (MOSS) and I want it to send the filter parameter to my document list web part (out of the box SharePoint).

1. I go in to the edit mode of the site.
2. I click the filter drop down menu and click to "Connect-Send filter string to-document list"
3. The popup appears but is blank.
4. After 5 minutes of waiting the popup is still blank.

I am using IE 8 with MOSS 2007. I have tried Firefox and Chrome but get the same behavior. Have any of you experienced this and do you have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: I would really need to resolv this question. Please help!

I get the same behavior even after switching from Vista to Windows 7. Though still using IE8. I have tried using using IE 7 on a WSS server but still the same blank popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get my popup. I think I solved it by manipulating the security settings in IE but I can't say for sure. It just startet working. Maybe it was after a restart of my computer or just IE, the settings doesn't really take effect before you restart the entire client...

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have MOSS with SP2, because IE8 support is included starting from SP2.

If that's not the issue, then you may want to help yourself with SharePoint Designer (it's free).

Comment: SP2 is installed. I tried using SharePoint Designer but first it doesn't ask which column I want to match filter param with and second the document list web part complains that there are too many connections to it when I connect it to the filter web part using SharePoint Designer!